# How to convert map search result to GIS Region Anylogic

Tags: java, gis, anylogic

I have to keep found location on GIS map as the search result in my model for further use.
To get a location on GIS map I use:

```
GISRegion gisRegion = null;
gisRegion = map.searchFirstRegion(cityName);
```

How to convert `gisRegion` to be cached and saved in the Model?
I have to execute this command as in the anylogic help, but with java:

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You already do it. Just store it in a separate variable:

1. create a variable "myGISRegion" on Main, make its type to `GISRegion`
2. on startup of Main, call the code `myGISRegion = map.searchFirstRegion(cityName);`
3. now, your variable can be used during the model run forever, it is also cached automatically (test this offline, it should still work)

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, but if I have 10000 "cityNames" my Model will get 10000 values of `gisRegion` on each startup. It will take much more time I think and I don't understand how I can search the region that I need in this list of region in this case? My idea was to get 10000 values of `gisRegion` and save them in the Model one time and work with.

Comment: that is how caching works. Try it once online, then turn off internet and rerun the model. The code should get the regions from the cache